# How do I change a value coded as "Yes" to a value of 1 in R?

Tags: r

The variables in my database are coded as "Yes" and "No" but I would like to have as "1" and "2".

I tried to create a new variable using `ifelse` but when I `list`'ed it, it didn't work, as follows:

```
CA <- ifelse((CANCER == "Yes"),1
ifelse(( CANCER == "No"),2 )))

list(CA)

[[1]]
NULL
```

Comment: Why?  I always prefer more informative labels like Yes and No; they're more informative and so I'm able to remember what they mean when I have to revisit an analysis six months later.  I'm not aware of any advantage of switching to numeric codes, save perhaps file size.

Comment: Because you might want to do numeric evaluations on the data.

Comment: @Aaron Who cares? Every programmer has their own preferences and programming needs.

Comment: There's a common misconception out there (due to old versions of SPSS, among other things), that to do analysis on a data set, the data, even categorical variables, must be stored as numeric values. This is not true with R, or any modern statistical software that I know of. I asked the question to get more information about their underlying needs, as I was worried this was an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 19):

If you want to use `ifelse`,

```
CA <- ifelse(CANCER=="Yes", 1, 2)
```

Comment: Note that this is based on evaluating a character string, so run unique() on that varable

Answer (score 7):

Assuming

```
levels(CANCER)
```

returns

```
Levels: yes no
```

it's probably easiest in your case if you just say

```
CA<-factor(as.numeric(CANCER))
```

However, generally you can also use

```
Cancer<-factor(CANCER)
```

Than assuming

```
levels(Cancer)
```

returns

```
Levels: yes no
```

You can change the levels thus

```
levels(Cancer)[1]<-"1"
levels(Cancer)[2]<-"2"
```

or switch labels accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

We need to know if your variable is a factor. Suppose

```
foo <- c("yes","no","no","yes")
```

If is.factor(foo) returns TRUE, e.g., if you did `foo <- factor(foo)`, then use

```
levels(foo) <- c("2", "1")
```

else use

```
foo[foo == "yes"] <- 1
foo[foo == "no"] <- 2
```

Also, list() doesn't do what (I think) you think it does. If you want to view the value of foo, just type in foo. After executing the code above...

```
foo
[1] 1 2 2 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's clever: is.factor(foo) FALSE is.character(foo) TRUE

Comment: @Momo, you're right, we don't know if the OP's variable is a factor or not. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: Great, but I only meant the result of relabeling should be a factor rather than a character vector.

Comment: @Momo, I disagree, actually - the result of relabeling should be a factor iff the original vector was a factor. No need to change data types as a side effect of relabeling.

Comment: @Aaron, no, if `foo` is a factor, then `foo[foo == "yes"] <- 1` will fail.

Comment: Thanks to all for the discussion. I'm working on it. I tried to change it since I'm going to use later for another variable. Ej table(death[Cancer==1],hospital, mean, na.rm=T)

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add (as it helped me when I first came across this type of thing) that unless explicitly stated, the levels of a factor are ordered alphabetically.

This wouldn't work for this particular question as the factor levels in the CANCER column are explicitly ordered. BUT, for any "yes" / "no" coded dataset that is read using

```
my_df <- read.csv(file = "myfile.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

"no" would be coded as `1` and "yes" would be coded as `2`, as N comes before Y in the alphabet.

Thus, in such a setting:

```
my_df$CANCER <- as.numeric(my_df$CANCER) - 1
```

Would be very useful as now every "no" is a `0` and every "yes" is a `1`

Hope that is helpful to someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

If you coerce to a factor with the levels set in the order `"yes","no"`:

```
foo <- factor(c("yes","no","no","yes"),levels=c("yes","no"))
```

You can simply coerce to numeric:

```
as.numeric(foo)
```

Which gives you:

```
[1] 1 2 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively - and potentially more flexible if you have more than 2 options - you can use the `merge()` function.

For example if you have this data frame:

```
dtf <- data.frame(CANCER = c("No", "Yes", "Yes", "No"),
                  x = c(4, 5, 6, 7), 
                  # Keep character variables as characters, do not create factors
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You can store the new way to code the value in another data frame :

```
moreinfo <- data.frame(CANCER = c("Yes", "No"),
                       CA = c(1, 2), 
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then merge it with the original data frame:

```
merge(dtf, moreinfo, by = "CANCER")

  CANCER x CA
1     No 4  2
2     No 7  2
3    Yes 5  1
4    Yes 6  1
```

Note: sorry about the `stringsAsFactors` parameter, it's necessary to prevent R from automatically creating factors with your character variables, I recommend using it also when you load data with `read.csv()`.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but you can do this with dplyr mutate and revalue

```
cancer_dat <- data.frame(CANCER = c("No", "Yes", "Yes", "No"),
                  x = c(4, 5, 6, 7))

cancer_dat =cancer_dat %>% mutate(CANCER = revalue(factor(cancer_dat$CANCER),
                                       c("Yes" = "1", "No" = "0")))
```

revalue allows you to change the factor name to something else in the form of "old name","new name"