# Creating binary variable from TRUE and NA observations in R

Tags: r, binary

My dataset has two types of categorical observations: One with two or more factors, another with one factor. I have a total of 12901 categorical and `NA` observations with 34 variables.

Columns 10 and 12:34 have observations with one factor, `TRUE` and `NA`.

**Question:** How can I get `TRUE` replaced with the value 1?

Here's an example of a variable with one factor:

```
> #First 34 observations
> Store4df$Cooking
[1] TRUE   NA   NA   NA TRUE   NA TRUE TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA TRUE   NA TRUE TRUE TRUE
[18]   NA TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA TRUE   NA TRUE TRUE   NA TRUE   NA TRUE TRUE
```

I tried performing the suggestion from another thread, but I have multiple variables. Link: [How do I change a value coded as "Yes" to a value of 1 in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033960/how-do-i-change-a-value-coded-as-yes-to-a-value-of-1-in-r) The commenter uses the `ifelse` function.

Here's my attempt at using the `ifelse` function:

```
> #If observation in column is TRUE, then replace with 1
> newdataset <- ifelse(Store4df[c(10, 12:34)] == "TRUE", 1)
Error in ifelse(Store4df[c(10, 12:34)] == "TRUE", 1) : 
  argument "no" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Your error indicates you are missing an argument, try `ifelse(x == "TRUE", 1, x)`.

Comment: Try `as.numeric(Store4df$Cooking)`. Or more generally `newdataset <- data.frame(lapply(Store4df[,c(10, 12:34)], as.numeric))`

Comment: `Store4df[,c(10, 12:34)] + 0` should do it