# Finding variables based on character values then turning them into numeric

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I'm pretty new to R and not sure how to find variables based on its' values and then turn them into numeric.

I have looked at [How do I change a value coded as "Yes" to a value of 1 in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033960/how-do-i-change-a-value-coded-as-yes-to-a-value-of-1-in-r) and [Convert data.frame column format from character to factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251326/convert-data-frame-column-format-from-character-to-factor).

These are my examples. I'm basically converting character variables that have only 'N' and 'Y' to 0 and 1, respectively. After going through some of the variables individually, I was wondering if there's a faster way to solve this problem. There are obviously other character variables that do not have "Y"/"N" so I don't want to just find all character variables and convert them into numeric. Please let me know if you have any ideas!

My codes:

```
df$var3<- ifelse(df$var3=="Y",1,0)
df$var4<- ifelse(df$var4=="Y",1,0)
df$var6<- ifelse(df$var5=="Y",1,0)
df$var7<- ifelse(df$var1=="Y",1,0)
```

sample df (pre):

```
n = c(2, 3, 5, 8, 10) 
var1 = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee") 
var2 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE) 
var3 = c("Y", "N", "Y", NA, "N") 
var4 = c("Y", "N", "Y", NA, "Y") 
var5 = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee") 
var6 = c("Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "N") 
var7 = c("Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N") 
df = data.frame(n, var1, var2, var3,var4,var5,var6,var7) 
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

sample df (post, what I want):

```
n = c(2, 3, 5, 8, 10) 
var1 = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee") 
var2 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE) 
var3 = c("1", "0", "1", NA, "0") 
var4 = c("1", "0", "1", NA, "1") 
var5 = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee") 
var6 = c("1", "0", "1", "1", "0") 
var7 = c("1", "0", "1", "0", "0") 
df = data.frame(n, var1, var2, var3,var4,var5,var6,var7)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easiest option is (if we know the index of the columns) to subset the columns of interest, convert it to logical matrix (`==`), coerce it to binary (`+`), and assign it back to the columns of interest

```
i1 <- c(4, 5, 7, 8)
df[i1] <- +(df[i1] == "Y")
```

---

If we don't have the index and have to individually check each column, then loop through the columns, check whether it is `factor` and have only the levels 'N', 'Y', then convert it to logical vector and change it to `integer` with as.integer

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) if(is.factor(x) && all(levels(x) %in% c("Y", "N"))) 
                  as.integer(x == "Y") else x)
```

Comment: The original data variables are in chr. Do you suggest first convert them into factors or should I try "if(is.character(x) && all(levels(x) %in% c(... "?

Comment: @Sun In that it case it would be `is.character(x) && all(unique(x) %in% c("N", "Y"))`

Comment: @akrun `dplyr::mutate_if` would be also useful, I suppose. It's basically the same answer just easier to comprehend/write but not necessarily faster. Cheers.

Comment: @M-M That should also work `df %>% mutate_if(~ is.character(.x) && all(unique(na.omit(.x)) %in% c("N", "Y")), funs(as.integer(.== "Y")))`

Comment: @Sun I would also include `na.omit` to take care of the NA elements `is.character(x) && all(unique(na.omit(x)) %in% c("N", "Y"))`

Comment: @akrun Thank you!     df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) if(is.character(x) && all(unique(na.omit(x)) %in% c("Y", "N"))) as.integer(x=="Y") else x) worked.

Comment: I was convinced that `as.integer(logical)` was the fastest way. I had always compared it with `0L + (logical)`. As it turns out, your way, with no `0L` is the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution works with R base and without need of loading additional R packages:

If you are looking to make changes throughout your complete dataframe, you can use below lines. The backdraw of using [elseif] in this specific scenario is that you are forced to set the [else] value, risking that some data might be overwritten.

```
df[df == 'N'] <- 0
df[df == 'Y'] <- 1
```